# How to formally define this square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, terminology, definition

I was wondering if there is formal name for a 3x3 matrix where the third column is the sum of the first two columns and the third row is the sum of the first two rows. In other words, a square matrix where both third row and column are redundant.

Comment: Do you mean *square* matrix rather than *squared* matrix?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix?wprov=sfla1 "a square matrix that is not invertible is called singular or degenerate."

Comment: Yes I meant square not squared. @DanUznanski do you mean that such matrix I describe is not invertibile? Has a zero determinant?

Comment: A square matrix (over a field) has linearly dependent columns (rows) iff its determinant is zero, hence not invertible.

Comment: The 3rd column (row) of a singular 3x3 matrix is of the form $c_3=\lambda c_1 + \mu c_2$, not necessarily $c_3=c_1 + c_2$ where $c_1,c_2$ are the first two columns (rows). So your matrix is a special type of a non-invertible matrix.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think this is what I was looking for. The fact that is non-invertible does not *necessarily* mean that it is problematic, right? This is a matrix of coefficients I will hand pick at a later stage for some calculations but I never work with the whole matrix otherwise…

Comment: Your matrix is of the form $$
\pmatrix{a&b&a+b\\c&d&c+d\\a+c&b+d&a+b+c+d}\,.
$$ Looks neat. Why problematic? Just don't try to invert it.

Comment: @KurtG. a question with this kind of detail would be helpful.

Comment: @CroCo Not sure what is left do to. OP's verbal description of the matrix is as good as that display and imo even better than a formal name (which I am not sure even exists).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is fully clear to me now.